# undefined method `content_length' for nil:NilClass fog storage [carrierwave]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have two models using the same uploader in a rails project  with carrierwave

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount :avatar, AvatarUploader
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

Then when I try to copy one image to another model

```
profile.avatar = brand.avatar
profile.save!
```

it fails with the following stacktrace

```
undefined method `content_length' for nil:NilClass
usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:238:in `size'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/proxy.rb:57:in `size'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:95:in `size'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:135:in `empty?'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:119:in `cache!'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:327:in `cache'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:179:in `avatar='
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:38:in `avatar='
/usr/share/nginx/cranberrychic/releases/20140213171925/app/services/brand_into_user_converter.rb:42:in `copy_avatar'
/usr/share/nginx/cranberrychic/releases/20140213171925/app/services/brand_into_user_converter.rb:13:in `convert'
(irb):64:in `block (2 levels) in irb_binding'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.78/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:486:in `block in transaction_with_trace_ActiveRecord_self_name_transaction'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.78/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:235:in `trace_execution_scoped'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.78/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:481:in `transaction_with_trace_ActiveRecord_self_name_transaction'
(irb):62:in `block in irb_binding'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:6:in `each'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:6:in `each'
(irb):59:in `irb_binding'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80:in `eval'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80:in `evaluate'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/irb/context.rb:254:in `evaluate'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:159:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:273:in `signal_status'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:156:in `block in eval_input'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:243:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `loop'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `catch'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `each_top_level_statement'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:70:in `block in start'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `catch'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `start'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

To me is a bug of carrierwave with fog storage, because in development with the file storage everything works as expected. When I try to copy an image from a model to another in any way possible with carrierwave, it fails with the same error

My carrierwave version is 0.9.0

and rails version is 3.2.13 and ruby 1.9.3-p327

Answer (score 2):

I believe you doing it wrong

```
profile.avatar = brand.avatar
```

will not work because `profile.avatar=` need a **file** object and `brand.avatar` don't give you a file object (it return you a uploader i.e avatar object)

I believe your looking for this approach

```
profile.remote_avatar_url = brand.avatar.url
profile.save!
```

Considering the `brand.avatar.url` give you a url from where carrierwave can download the file

More information about `remote_{uploader}_url` can also be found in Carrierwave [Readme](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/README.md)

Hope this help